# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al generar un archivo docx a html me reconozca los tildes etc.?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Hasta el momento me funciona bien pero solo cuando uso contenido en ingles.
Lo que estoy intentando hacer es subir un archivo word con un input file y este convertirlo en html para poder insertar el html a mi editor de texto(Summernote).

Me guié de este link:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Convert-Word-Document-Doc-Docx-to-HTML-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

```
public JsonResult ConvertirDocumentoHtml(HttpPostedFileBase archDocu)
    {
        object documentFormat = 8;
        string randomName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        object htmlFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + randomName + ".htm";
        string directoryPath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + randomName + "_files";
        object fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + Path.GetFileName(archDocu.FileName);

        //Si el directorio no está presente, créelo.
        if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Temp/")))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Temp/"));
        }

        //Sube el documento de Word y guárdalo en la carpeta Temp.
        archDocu.SaveAs(fileSavePath.ToString());

        //Abra el documento de Word en el fondo..
        _Application applicationclass = new Application();
        applicationclass.Documents.Open(ref fileSavePath);
        applicationclass.Visible = false;
        Document document = applicationclass.ActiveDocument;

        //Guardar el documento de Word como archivo HTML.
        document.SaveAs(ref htmlFilePath, ref documentFormat);

        //Close the word document.
        document.Close();

        //Read the saved Html File.
        string wordHTML = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(htmlFilePath.ToString());

        //Loop and replace the Image Path.
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(wordHTML, "<v:imagedata.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            wordHTML = Regex.Replace(wordHTML, match.Groups[1].Value, "Temp/" + match.Groups[1].Value);
        }

        //Delete the Uploaded Word File.
        System.IO.File.Delete(fileSavePath.ToString());

        //ViewBag.WordHtml = wordHTML;

        var docuHtml = wordHTML;

        return Json(docuHtml);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si editas con el notepad el archivo html que se genera en la ruta htmlFilePath, puedes ver que los caracteres con acepto se visualizan correctamente ?

Comment: El problema es que cuando obtiene el archivo y lo genera a html ya se muestra con eso caracteres extraños.

Comment: si abres el docx que subes al sitio este se guarda correctamente ? digo puedes ver estos caracteres

Answer (score 1):

El problema se relaciona con el `encoding` utilizado cuando se persiste el archivo como html

Podrias probar algo como esto

```
doc.WebOptions.Encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
doc.SaveAs2("C:\\Temp\\Test.htm", MsWord.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML);
```

[Save Word to UTF-8 Encoded HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026716/save-word-to-utf-8-encoded-html)

aunque tambien el `SaveAs` tiene este parametro

[Document.SaveAs Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/k98f9hzs(v%3Dvs.120))

Comment: Gracias me ayuda a orientarme mejor y solucione el problema.

Comment: @Erickchambi Si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor recuerda **[aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).** Saludos.